# Odoo 11 + Postgresql all on AWS - not able to connect from my onpremise machine

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, odoo-11

I'm hosting Odoo on AWS and need to connect from my local machine. I am using AWS Certificate Manager instead of using a local .pem file ( no SSL configuration done on Apache as I am using AWS CM).

My odoo application works well, If I type https://myodoosite.com it works well.

What I need is to connect to the Postgresql DB on myodoosite.com

I can connect to the Postgresql DB from within the myodoosite.com server by uisng the command  **$psql -U postgres odoo_prod**

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

WHen I connect from my local, it says " Is the server running at  myodoosite.com accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?  "

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand correctly your situation:

- Odoo, Apache and PostgreSQL in one or multiple EC2 instances in AWS.
- Load Balancer with SSL termination (using certificate from Certificate Manager) that exposes only your Odoo/Apache http service.

You probably have firewall rules in security groups preventing the PostgreSQL traffic in tcp port 5432. You need to open port 5432 to be accessible from your onpremise IP-address. You can do this by enabling the predefined PostgreSQL type in PostgreSQL EC2 instance's Security Group and set your IP address in the source address. Please note that this way the database is accessible for all traffic coming from that IP or IP range. So if you use shared IP this could be a problem.

Another easy and secure way to connect to PostgreSQL is to tunnel the traffic from your workstation with ssh. This is usable if you already have ssh port open and you do not want to open PostgreSQL port to public internet.

Comment: Thanks Veikko for the answers, yes your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks Veikko for the answers, yes your understanding is correct about my application environment. I added 5432 into the security group of this EC2. That is for both incoming and outgoing traffic. Still it does not work.  <br/>   By the way, could you please help me to provide more details on this "tunnel the traffic from your workstation with ssh" ?  I am not a networking expert :) <br> If you can provide me step by step actions to achieve this, that would be awesome :)